# << exFAT-fs: invalid fs_name >>

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ssd, exfat

I recently bought a Dell computer (G15 5530) that came with one 1TB SSD. I upgrade it, and added a second SSD with 2T.

The 2T SSD was partitioned using `ext4` and `ntfs`. In the `ext4` partition, I installed `Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS` and in the `ntfs` partition, I installed `Windows 11 Pro`, so my system has dual boot.

The 1T SSD was formatted using `exFAT` as I need to share data between Linux/Windows.

The output from `fdisk -l` is:
(for a reason I don't understand, the output doesn't show the `nvme0n1p5` device formatted as ext4 (see the last image below)).

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1.86 TiB, 2048408248320 bytes, 4000797360 sectors
Disk model: ADATA SX8200PNP                         
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B1EC21C0-4E8C-4D76-AABC-0EF5269888A8

Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     206847     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2     206848     239615      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3     239616 1635187415 1634947800 779.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1635188736 1636863999    1675264   818M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 1636866048 4000796671 2363930624   1.1T Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: BC901 NVMe SK hynix 1024GB              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A3F425B5-9FEA-4425-97E9-C8CFB71E6446

Device         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1  2048 2000408575 2000406528 953.9G Microsoft basic data
```

The exFAT partition is mounted in `fstab` as:

```
/dev/nvme1n1p1  /home/icamps/Dados exfat users,exec,rw,suid,dev,atime,diratime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000 0 0
```

The problem is that from time to time, I cannot boot, and I'm getting the error shown in the image below:

[image]

After entering `ENTER`, and then rebooting, I can boot normally.

How can I fix this issue?

Regards,

Camps

PS: Screenshot from DISK utility:

[image]